# No preview of layout xml file in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTePt.png)

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
dependencies
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextLabelHint</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="s">false</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/Widget.App.Switch</item>
</style>
```

how to fix it?
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'